# Captain America with svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

How I can do this star right with svg? I must use svg and I try with points but not work. I mustn't use element path. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" fill="blue" />
       <polygon points="50,25 30,80 75,40 25,40 70,70" style="fill:white;"/> 
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean to say you want the star to be within the blue area? And why  not use `path` element? It is also SVG only.

Comment: Please see @frhd's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37009395/736893

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems a bit closer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="100" height="100">
 
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
  
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" fill="blue" />
  
 <polygon points="50,25 35,70 73,42 26,42 65,70" style="fill:white;"/> 
  
</svg> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

*updated to use @frhd's number, make community wiki,*

*please see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009395/736893) for calculations*

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the most accurate points for the pentastar, you can get them easily from the underlying pentagon.

[image]

A simple js function to obtain these points is something like this ([REPL](https://repl.it/CMbS/4), which by the way you can use for polygons with any **n** edges):

```
var n = 5;
var points = [];
for (var i=0; i < n; i++) {
    var x = 50;
    var y = -50;
    var r = 25;
    points.push([x + r * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / n),
                 y + r * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / n)]);
}
```

Result is the pentagon points clock-wise, starting at the top (use all values as positive ones):

```
[ [ 50, -25 ],
  [ 73.77641290737884, -42.27457514062631 ],
  [ 64.69463130731182, -70.22542485937369 ],
  [ 35.30536869268818, -70.22542485937369 ],
  [ 26.22358709262116, -42.27457514062632 ] ]
```

Your order would be `points[x], where x = 0, 3, 1, 4, 2`.

And using them for your example rounded to the nearest pixel:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" fill="blue" />
 <polygon points="50,25 35,70 73,42 26,42 65,70" style="fill:white;"/> 
</svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is way better than my answer where I just guessed.

Answer (score 2):

Here with path

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">

  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />

  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" fill="blue" />

  <!-- <polygon points="50,25 30,80 75,40 25,40 70,70" style="fill:white;"/> -->
  <path fill="#fff" d="m50,25 5,17h18l-14,11 5,17-15-10-15,10 5-17-14-11h18z" />
</svg>
```